Simulate :hover, :active, and :focus states to test styling
I'm building a restyle for a certain component library to implement a company design system. I'd like to be able to render components styled as if they were hovered / pressed / focused to be able to show and test the styles applied when the component is in one of these states.
AFAICS there's no way to actually simulate those element states. Similar questions are most often concerned with simulating the corresponding events, which doesn't concern me, as it isn't able to actually simulate the :hover / :active / :focus styling. Others suggest using classNames in styles instead of pseudo-classes when implementing the styles, which is not applicable when not in [full] control of the styles in question.
I'm using Emotion for styling, so I don't create styles directly. They are generated automatically as a number of <style> nodes in document head.

I was able to achieve the desired outcome by manipulating the generated <style> nodes, duplicating the relevant parts of CSS selectors, so that for every selector using :hover / :active / :focus I added a copy of it that applied a class selector instead. Then I applied that same class when I needed to show the specific state styling.
export enum StateClass {
  Hover = '__demo-hover',
  Focus = '__demo-focus',
  Active = '__demo-active'
}

const simulateStatesInRule = (rule: CSSRule) => {
  if (rule instanceof CSSMediaRule) {
    Array.from(rule.cssRules).forEach(simulateStatesInRule);
    return;
  }

  if (!(rule instanceof CSSStyleRule) || !rule.selectorText) return;

  rule.selectorText = rule.selectorText.split(',').flatMap((part) => {
    if ([StateClass.Hover, StateClass.Active, StateClass.Focus].some((stateClass) => part.includes(`.${stateClass}`)))
      return []; // don't keep adding selectors forever
    if (/:(?:hover|focus|active)/.test(part))
      return [
        part,
        part
          .replace(/:hover/g, `.${StateClass.Hover}`)
          .replace(/:focus/g, `.${StateClass.Focus}`)
          .replace(/:active/g, `.${StateClass.Active}`)
      ];
    return [part];
  }).join(',');
};

const simulateStatesInStyle = (style: HTMLStyleElement) =>
  Array.from(style.sheet?.cssRules ?? []).forEach(simulateStatesInRule);

export const simulateStatesUsingClasses () => {
  const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) =>
    mutations.forEach(({ addedNodes }) =>
      Array.from(addedNodes)
        .filter((node) => node instanceof HTMLStyleElement)
        .forEach(simulateStatesInStyle)
    )
   );

   observer.observe(document.head, { childList: true });
   document.head.querySelectorAll('style').forEach(simulateStatesInStyle);

   return () => {
    observer.disconnect();
  };
}

